# Does the expectation of a random variable belong to the convex closure of its pointwise values?

Tags: measure-theory, expected-value, convex-geometry

Let $S$ be a closed convex set (of a Banach space, not necessarily of finite dimension), $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}(\Omega), \mu)$ be a probability space, and $\phi : \Omega \to S$ be an integrable function (or a random variable of finite expectation if you prefer).

Surely, if $\mu$ is countable, we can write it,
$$
\mu = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} p_n \delta_{x_n},
$$
for some sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements in $\Omega$ and nonnegative weights $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, summing to $1$. Then, clearly, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by convexity of $S$
$$
\frac{\sum_{k \leq n} p_k \phi(x_k)}{\sum_{k \leq n} p_k} \in S,
$$ 
then by closure of $S$, the limit belongs to $S$.

My question is, does this statement hold when $\mu$ is not supposed countable? Namely, is the following always true?
$$
\int_\Omega \phi \mathrm{d}\mu \in S
$$

Comment: Is $\delta_{x_n}$ supposed to be the unit mass centered at $x_n$? I ask since it shows up in only the first sum, while $\phi$ is in the second. Want to ensure its not a typo.

Comment: Yes, it's the unit-mass centered at $x_n$. $\mu$ being a countable measure can be explicitly written that way.

Comment: Is $\int_\Omega \phi\,d\mu$ the Bochner integral, Pettis integral, or...?

Comment: The Bochner integral seems more suited to me, $S$ is a subset of a Banach space.

Comment: I guess it's solved then, with the answer of kimchi lover, and if I suppose $\phi$ is Bochner integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximate $\phi$ by simple functions.  In particular, for each $\epsilon>0$ you can use your argument above to show $\int \phi d\mu\in S_\epsilon$ where $S_\epsilon$ is the set of points at distance $\le\epsilon$ to $S$.  The sets $S_\epsilon$ are closed and convex, and $S=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}S_\epsilon$.

Added in an edit. Or you could use the Hahn-Banach theorem.  If $\mu$ is not in $S$ there is a continuous linear function $\lambda$ that separates them, and from that a contradiction is easy to exhibit: $\langle \lambda,\phi \rangle\ge a$ with probability $1$ but $\langle \lambda,\mu\rangle\le b$ for some real  $b<a$.

Comment: Wouldn't that rely on the relative compactness of $S$? Precisely, in the density of simple functions in measurable functions.

Comment: I was trying to find how to approximate $\phi$ with simple functions. But with Bochner integral, you ask $\phi$ to be approximable by simple functions. I'll type up all details before marking this as an answer just to be sure, but I think this closes my question.